# Flex mobile, AIR: Left swipe menu

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I develop my application with `Flex Builder`, `Adobe AIR`. And I want to create similar to `Adobe Reader` left-side menu. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean the left side menu from the Adobe Reader iPad version ? or ?

Comment: Almost. It's the same menu, but I want it to be able to hide

Answer (score 0):

I am not near my desk right now, but maybe something like the 'SplitViewNavigator' might be a good approach.

Code pasted from link provided:

```
<s:SplitViewNavigator id="svn" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:ViewNavigator id="leftNav" width="30%" height="100%" firstView="views.LeftView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="rightNav" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.RightView"/>
</s:SplitViewNavigator>
```

DevGirl has a great article on this with a good example, you can use this as a base for what you are trying to achieve.

http://devgirl.org/2011/12/01/flex-mobile-development-splitviewnavigator-tutorial/